# My side bar is missing from new pages.

Tags: sidebar

Really not sure what is going on here.

First tried creating a new page with "Default Template" - Header and Footer look good, but no sidebar.

I then decided to create a custom page template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: BeautyBar
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    -->Your content will go here<--

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Still no sidebar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your theme have a sidebar.php? have you checked if there is any output to the html in the browser, but possibly invisible on the screen? what theme are you working with?

Comment: Have you read the description of the [get_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) function?

Comment: Sounds like your sidebars are conditionally loaded. Find `dynamic_sidebar` in your theme and post the surrounding code-- should be in `sidebar.php` as already suggested.